# how to get a copy of exist git repository to new repository

Tags: git, github

Already development is going on with master branch. Now, want to create (checkout) another branch and on different server.

Requirement: I am developing code on PaaS (like Windows Azure). Now, I want to keep my code(mirror) including history on github. In future, I want to access all git commits/logs.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't exactly understand what your requirement is. Do you have a local git repository and you want to push it to github?

Comment: I am developing application on Windows Azure platform. It would expire soon. I could  not access code after expired. Now, I want to push my code in git hub including all commits. Pleae let me know if still not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand from your comments, you want to clone your already existing local git repository to github. For that (assuming you already have created a github account):

1. Go to github and [Create a new repository](https://github.com/new)
2. From your new repository home page copy the "HTTPS clone URL" from the right sidebar.
3. In your local git shell, do `git remote add origin <remote repository URL>`
4. Then just do `git push origin master`

That's all. If you want a separate branch, you can create a local branch with `git checkout -b newBranch` and do a `git push origin newBranch`